# Why do members of Psi Corp wear black gloves?

Tags: babylon-5

I notice that members of Psi Corp like Bester and Talia Winters wear black gloves. Why do that given that black gloves are hot? They are not comfortable. Does it have something to do with their mental powers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JMS addressed this in a [Q&A](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/guide/009.html) on the excellent Midwinter website. in short, wearing gloves minimises the risk of *accidental scans.*

> ***"Talia, like all Psi Corps members, wears gloves because she has to,
> when in public, to minimize physical contact and accidental scans.** As
> for others wearing gloves...sometimes it's a fashion statement ... and
> other times, well, space is very very cold...."*
>
> <sub><sup>[Midwinter: Deathwalker](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/guide/009.html)</sup></sub>

Wearing gloves is an obligation on Psi Corps members and part of the official uniform, subject to 'enforcement'.

> **"Stuff like wearing gloves is only enforced if you're a member of Psi
> Corps;** Allysa wasn't. In addition, though she had P10 *potential*, the
> talent was sporadic, came and went."
>
> <sub><sup>[Midwinter: Legacies](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/guide/017.html)</sup></sub>

---

We learn in [Deadly Relations - Bester Ascendant](http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/Deadly_Relations_-_Bester_Ascendant) that the gloves are given to young Psi Corp trainees as a mark of leaving Cadre Prime and becoming fully fledged members of the Corp.

> *It didn't matter, because he suddenly understood. The teachers weren't
> in charge, any more than he was. The Corps was mother and father, not
> any of the individuals in it. Teacher Hua's words began to make more
> sense.*
>
> *When it was over, they were given black robes to wear, and more
> important-gloves. Al pulled his on, felt them close about his fingers.
> Gloves, at long last.*
>
> *He was no longer a child.*

Comment: "*space is very very cold*" - I don't think a pair of gloves would make much difference if you were actually out in space ...

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Sure, but they're normally traveling in tin cans, far above the world.

Comment: In which case, space being cold is no longer relevant, since said tin cans are presumably heated somehow.

Comment: @Randal'Thor JMS often has a tendency to toss a silly answer or two out as well as the more serious ones.